# Scope and maintainance of variable state in self invoking anonymous function vs anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, self-invoking-function

I want to understand the way  anonymous self invoking function is able to maintain the last updated state of variable but why is it not possible in case of normal anonymous functions .Both functions are closures
 still are behaving differently while maintaining the previous state of variable.
ex:

```
var selfInvokingfunc= (function () {
    var a=2;
    var myprivatefunction = function () {
        a=a+2;
        console.log(a);

    }
    return {
        mypublicfunction : function () {
            myprivatefunction();
        }
    }
})();

selfInvokingfunc.mypublicfunction() ;//a is 4
selfInvokingfunc.mypublicfunction();  // a is 6

var nonSelfInvokingAnonymousFunction = function () {
    var a=2;
    var myprivatefunction = function () {
        a=a+2;
        console.log(a);
    }

    return {
        mypublicfunction : function () {
            myprivatefunction();
        }
    }
};

nonSelfInvokingAnonymousFunction().mypublicfunction(); //a is 2
nonSelfInvokingAnonymousFunction().mypublicfunction(); //a is 2
```

Same works fine for  non self invoking if invoked as :

```
var temp=nonSelfInvokingAnonymousFunction();
temp.mypublicfunction() ; // a is 4
temp.mypublicfunction(); // a is 6
```

Please help me understand the same.

Comment: `selfInvokingfunc` is, despite the variable name, not a function. It just holds the object that the IIFE returned - really like the `temp` variable in your third snippet.

Comment: That is because you are executing `nonSelfInvokingAnonymousFunction` all over again, when it's 2 twice. Notice that you don't have to call your `selfInvokingfunc`, which really returns an Object that has a function property which returns another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the main body of the outer function is executed and the lines:

```
var a=2;
var myprivatefunction = function () {
// ...
```

are run, a new binding for those variables are created in memory.

With the self-invoking function, since it's executed immediately and *once*, there then exists *one* binding for the `a` variable, which the `mypublicfunction` property can see via the closure.

In contrast, with your `nonSelfInvokingAnonymousFunction`, every time you invoke it, you create a separate binding for `a`:

```
nonSelfInvokingAnonymousFunction().mypublicfunction(); //a is 2
// ^^^ creates an a           ^^^^
nonSelfInvokingAnonymousFunction().mypublicfunction(); //a is 2
// ^^^ creates a SEPARATE a   ^^^^
```

When you have two separate bindings for the `a` variable, calling `mypublicfunction` on a function that closes over *one* of the bindings will have no effect on the *other* binding.

In your last code, when you do

```
var temp = nonSelfInvokingAnonymousFunction();
//         ^^^ creates an a           ^^^^
temp.mypublicfunction() ; // a is 4
temp.mypublicfunction(); // a is 6
```

You create a single `a`, and a `temp` whose `mypublicfunction` function closes over that one `a`, so calling `mypublicfunction` multiple times results in that `a` changing multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, i understood the concept.